Database migrations under DynamoDB - Move entries to code, and create a pipeline
We have a DynamoDB based config. We want to transfer all the configs inside the DDB to a code package. We then want to create a pipeline from the said code package to the DDB, which then handles all the changes inside the DDB.
I believe this comes under the topic of "Database migrations", and some examples are FlyWay (but that is used for SQL based DBs)
Wanted to check whether there are some solutions already built for this.
